# What is the actual difference between Data Warehouse & Big Data?

Tags: database, bigdata, data-warehouse

I know what is Data Warehouse & what is Big Data.
But I am confused with Data Warehouse Vs Big Data.
Both are same with different names or both are different(Conceptually & Physically).